# Is it possible to force the next boot to be a recovery mode boot with a bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: macos, imac

I wanted to test the new recovery mode in Lion and can't find a way to enter that mode using a bluetooth keyboard.

There are steps how to get a [single user mode](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/8475.html) or [safe boot](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1455) using `sudo nvram boot-args`

I was wondering if anyone has uncovered how to get into recovery mode without having a hard wired USB keyboard. As described in the comments - this iMac is older than the ones that make bluetooth available at boot time which is why I'm looking to write something before the reboot progresses to a point where bluetooth is not available to override the default boot selection list.

Comment: What computer/keyboard are you using? I can get to single user mode, safe boot, etc. using an Apple Wireless Keyboard and an iMac. Im guessing your mac doesn't detect the keyboard until OSX has loaded completely?

Comment: It is a mid 2009 24" iMac - didn't ship with bluetooth KB. I'm using the standard, newest aluminum apple keyboard. I think the newer hardware can drive the keyboard earlier in the boot process and I'm out of luck with this generation, but it's a hunch at this point. My question was a bit vague - great questions - I'll likely edit it later to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This model seems to respect the option key only - so that will get me to the startup manager and I can select the Recovery HD.

I have not had luck getting command R to work but it's clearly meant to work as well - perhaps that's for newer macs with better bluetooth hardware (or my mac is just cranky and not working as designed)

Answer (score 1):

At least, on macbook pros (10.9 -> 10.14.6) you can run the command

```
sudo nvram recovery-boot-mode=unused
```

And the macbook pro will boot into recovery when you restart, the flag will be removed from nvram so you boot normal the next time after it.

Comment: This works on macOS Catalina 10.15 too.